# Find the PerformancePoint "Dashboards" SPList

Tags: web-part, performancepoint

I need to write a WebPart that finds all the SPList that can store PerformancePoint dashboards (like the default "Dashboards" one that is present in every BI site).

What's the best method to understand is a SPList can be used to hold deployed dashboards? In other words how does Dashboard Designer pick up the Document Libraries where to deploy?

Thanks,
 Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

You could do a foreach statement on the lists to see which one has the PerformancePoint content types in the SPList.ContentTypes property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypes.aspx